# E Seguro fazer consultas mysql usando valores de cookie?

Tags: php, mysql

Ola, seguinte fiz um sistema que funciona, porém estou com dúvida se é seguro usá-lo para assegurar que tenha uma maior segurança ou ao menos tentar obtê-la. Estou usando uma função que só lê números no *mysql*, porém ainda sou iniciante e gostaria de uma segunda opinião a respeito.

Alguém poderia me informar se é seguro ou se há algo mais para deixar seguro?

Código:

```
$id = $_COOKIE["id"]; //Nome do cookie
$novoId = "$cont[id]"; // Novo id, value exemplo "1,2,3,4" adiciona novo valor apos virgula

if (!preg_match("/\b{$novoId}\b/", $id)) {
    setcookie("id", $id .= "{$novoId},");
}

$historico = explode(",", $id);

$histanime = array_filter($historico, function($value) {
    /* Retorna apenas os números inteiros */
    return is_numeric($value);
});

if(($quantidade = count($histanime)) > 30){
    $histanime = array_slice($histanime, $quantidade - 30, 30);
}

$ids5 = implode(",", $histanime) ;
```

e a consulta no *mysql* e feita com um *while*:

```
$cont = mysql_query("SELECT title,titulo2,url,imagen FROM `lista` WHERE aid IN($ids5)");
while (list($title, $titulo2, $url, $Imagen) = mysql_fetch_array($cont))
```

Comment: ele so pode consultar números, @Marcelo Rafael, os usuários são guardados em outra tabela. quanto as números eles representa apenas id de páginas do site.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, funções com prefixo `mysql_` **são obsoletas** e foram removidas no PHP7, para garantir que seus códigos funcionem use PDO ou MySQLI.

Sobre a segurança do uso de cookies será o mesmo *nível de segurança* de fazer via `POST` e `GET`, qualquer usuário pode mudar os valores e tentar fazer um ataque sql-injection, então o problema não é se é COOKIE, POST ou GET, o importante é você garantir que os valores passados não contenham dados inesperados.

Da maneira que você fez só passa os tipo numéricos:

```
$histanime = array_filter($historico, function($value) {
    /* Retorna apenas os números inteiros */
    return is_numeric($value);
});
```

O que provavelmente já garante alguma segurança, então não importa a origem, importa é o tratamento que você dá a esses dados.

As pessoas pensam que a falha de segurança esta exclusivamente ligada a ser cookie, get ou post, tem gente que acredita que POST é mais seguro, o que é um engano, qualquer um que domine um pouco HTTP com o uso de uma ferramenta como `wget` ou `curl`, pode experimentar atacar o seu servidor, então o que é importante de se resolver é:

- o tratamento dos dados (o que você já fez)
- revisar com atenção os códigos
- usar as APIs modernas
- se possivel usar `bindParam` (ou `bindValue`)

Comment: no caso esses ids que passariam "números", seriam apenas id de páginas do site, quanto a versão do Php que estou usado creio que seja a 5.4 ou 5.3

Comment: @Gabriel php5.3 e 5.4 são antigos já, ainda tem servidores que o usam, mas o futuro é o php7 (já estamos no 7.2), altere os seus códigos para mysqli ou pdo o quanto antes, pois se vossos servidores fizerem upgrade e abandonarem versões antigas do php então seus códigos irão falhar, já que funções com prefixo `mysql_` já são desencorajadas a muito tempo.

Comment: @Gabriel sim, eu entendi que são só numeros, eu mesmo comentei sobre isto na resposta, sobre o seu uso do `array_filter`, o que importa é entender que não é COOKIE que é inseguro (tecnicamente), mas sim o tratamento dado aos "dados", o que você já resolver filtrando eles.